# Problem passing data from HttpServlet to JSP

Tags: java, jsp, getattribute

I am working on a project that gathers data that I want to display
in a web browser. The project uses java and JSP on a linux
operating system:

```
    Linux roe 4.19.0-13-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.19.160-2 (2020-11-28) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I am running Apache Tomcat server 8.0.53 and java jdk 1.8.

I found the following web page, which I refer to below as 'Ref_1':

[https://www.programmergate.com/pass-data-servlet-jsp]

'Ref_1' gives a good description on how to move data from a java
HttpServlet controller to a JSP target page. My target page is
the file 'list.jsp'.

In the java controller, I have followed 'Ref_1' and added the code:

```
request.setAttribute("jja","jjaTest");                
request.getRequestDispatcher("list.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

When I run this code in eclipse, I can verify that the request
object gets set with the attribute 'jja' set to 'jjaTest'.

My understanding is that the 'request' and 'response' objects are passed to
JSP as implicit objects that are available as Expression Language (EL)
variables or by referring to the implied objects by name
as 'request' or 'response'.

In the file, 'list.jsp', I have added the following code, as suggested
by 'Ref_1':

```
<body>
   <div>
       <p>Test is ${jja}</p>
       <p>Test attribute is <%= request.getAttribute("jja") %> </p>
   </div></body>
```

When 'list.jsp' is displayed in the browser, the results are:

**Test is**

**Test attribute is null**

In the first output line, printing the EL variable ${jja} shows nothing. I assume this means
the value was not successfully passed from the controller. Or if
it was, it is not being read correctly.

In the second output line, request.getAttribute("jja") prints a 'null' value.

Obviously, I'm doing something wrong. Does anyone see the error?

P.S. stackoverflow referred me to  a number of similar questions, which I have reviewed and I plan to review again. One of the questions was very similar, but did not have a resolution. So, to date, I have not yet found a solution in any of the similar questions.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to navigate to the servlet or controller url instead of directly to the jsp.

I've created a small application to show how this works.
https://github.com/Crydust/so66555347

Notice how requesting "http://localhost:8080/so66555347/list.jsp" directly fails to show the attribute. While "http://localhost:8080/so66555347/ListServlet" works.

Comment: Currently, my controller forwards to the JSP with the request dispatcher forward statement above. I don't know another method to navigate to 'list.jsp'. Ultimately, this file is targeted because that is where the resulting list is displayed by the application.

Comment: So ... in your webbrowser you're surfing to "http://localhost/website/MyServlet". Which then internally sets attributes on the request and dispatches to the jsp. Not surfing to "http://localhost/website/list.jsp" directly without going throught the servlet? Right?